# Read Spring ModelAndView objects in Pug

Tags: spring-mvc, pug, jade4j

My front-end application uses Pug to generate the `index` page.

Being a Vue.js application, it can be served from Java (production purpose) or Node (develop purpose)

**DEVELOP**

Variables in `index.pug` are injected by running this command:

```
pug -P -s -O ./variables.js -o ./ index.pug
```

`variables.js` is something like:

```
variables = {
  value: 'something'
}
```

Variables inside `index.pug` can be readed like:

```
if variables.value == 'something'
  //show some tags ecc...
```

All is working fine.

**PRODUCTION**

To render index.pug server side I use [jade4j](https://github.com/neuland/jade4j)

In index controller I do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm")
public ModelAndView indexView(...) {
   ... other code here...
   ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
   mav.addObject("value", "something");
   return mav;
}
```

but `value` can be readed in a `script.` tag by this syntax `'#{value}'` like in this example:

```
script.
   console.log('#{value}') // prints "something"
```

How can I read `value` in the **DEVELOP** scenario above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/marlonbernardes/spring-boot-jade) has given me the answer.

It was pretty simple after all... something I've never tried cause thought it was too dummy.

Just use `#{value}` without `''` inside the "Pug code", with it otherwise.